Can a minimal separating set in a chordal graph ever be a maximal clique on its own?
I'm currently reading Daphne Koller's book on Probabilistic Graphical Models, and, in the proof of theorem 4.12, the authors state something that I cannot wrap my head around.
The authors state that in an undirected chordal graph, a minimal separating set $\mathbf{S}$ for two variables, $X_{1}$ and $X_{2}$ can either be a subset of a maximal clique or a maximal clique on its own. While I understand why, due to chordality,  $\mathbf{S}$ has to be a complete subgraph and how $\mathbf{S}$ can be a subset of a maximal clique, I do not understand how it can ever be a maximal clique on its own. It seems to me that the same requirement that the graph be chordal necessarily makes $\mathbf{S}$ a subset of maximal clique.
To recap the statement of the theorem and the outline of the proof: Theorem 4.12 Every undirected chordal graph $\mathcal{H}$ has a clique tree $\mathcal{T}$. The proof goes like this:

Let $\mathcal{H}$ be an undirected, chordal graph of size > 1.
Two nodes $X_{1}$ and $X_{2}$ are connected, but not directly.
Let $\mathbf{S}$ be a minimal subset of nodes that separates $X_{1}$ and $X_{2}$.
Let $\mathbf{W_{1}}$ and $\mathbf{W_{2}}$ be some partition of the variables $\mathcal{X}-\mathcal{S}$ into two disjoint components, such that $\mathbf{W_{i}}$ encompasses the connected component containing $X_{i}$.
Create an induced graph $\mathcal{H_{1}} = \mathcal{H}[\mathbf{W_{1} \cup \mathbf{S}}]$.

It is after this step that the authors state:

"Beacuse $\mathbf{S}$ is a complete connected subgraph, it is either a maximal clique or a subset of some maximal clique in $\mathcal{H}$"

The authors do, later on, address a case where $\mathbf{S}$ is a maximal clique, but at this point I already cannot follow them. How can $\mathbf{S}$ be a maximal clique on its own?

I agree with you, and I will try to write up a proof of what your intuition is telling you. It is a bit involved.

Thank you @MathieuRundström , I'd very much appreciate it. I am stuck on this part and cannot move on.

I answered a related question from 8 years ago just now, see my answer below. I hope this answers your question.

Thank you @MathieuRundström , much appreciated.

One can argue that in the component containing $X_i$ after deleting $\mathbf{S}$, there exists a vertex complete to $\mathbf{S}$ in the original graph. This means that $\mathbf{S}$ it not a maximal clique. I gave a proof of this fact here: Chordal graphs - simple property of a minimal separator. That proof is not very short, and there might not exist a nice simple argument (I'd be happy to be wrong here!), which is why I believe that the authors of your book might have just treated this "non-existent" case as valid, as this gives a shorter proof of their theorem 4.12.
